# Android ListView recycling translated view

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a listView swipe to select multiple items. Essentially the user will swipe right on an item to reveal a checkbox/layout to show that the item is selected.

I have the onTouchListener working to translate the view right, but the problem is ListView recycles views. Which means translated views show up even when they should not be.

I am attaching the onTouchListener in the getView() method of my adapter like so:

root.setOnTouchListener(new MySwipeListener(holder,position));

[This is a GIF of my problem](http://i.imgur.com/qcvXV34.gifv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is maintain the state in a ArrayList i.e create a an arraylist(better if you maintain a flag in your pojo/bean class) and in the 
onBIndViewHolder do something like this.

```
  ArrayList<Boolean> isTranslated;

  public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
   if(isTranslated.get(position)){
    holder.container.setTranslationX(100);
   }
  else{
  holder.container.setTranslationX(0);
   }
       ///TODO rest of your logic

  }
```

Dont forget to update the arraylist with the swipestate/translated state.